# C# ASP.NET Excel Interop Error - not enough available memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, interop

I have an ASP.NET Webforms application that creates an excel workbook using the following code:

```
Excel._Workbook oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
...
oWB.SaveAs(@"C:\bws\bsite\Reports\productionmatrix" + timeStamp + ".xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
```

When the application attempts to save the file, I get the following error:

> Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space.
>
> • To make more memory available, close workbooks or programs you no longer need.
>
> • To free disk space, delete files you no longer need from the disk you are saving to.

To resolve this problem, I have tried the following:

Updated the properties setting in Microsoft Excel Application using dcomcnfg for Network Service to allow Local and Remote Launch and Activation.  I also, set the Identity for this site's Application Pool in IIS to NetworkService.  I changed the permissions for the folder to which I am saving these files to full control for the Network Service user.

A blog site suggested I change the Identify for the Microsoft Excel Application using dcomcnfg to:  The Interactive User.  However, this results in the following error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

I also set the ASP.NET Impersonation to enabled which results in the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error
> An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

Can anyone suggest a modification that will enable the application to save an excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Could the message mean just what it says? Maybe you're out of disk space. Are you creating these on demand and streaming them? If so, are you deleting them when they're no longer needed?

Comment: Scott, there is tons of disc space available.  From my understanding, this some irrelevant exception that has nothing to do with the underlying problem.

Comment: @KermitLove were you able to resolve this issue? I am currently stuck on this.